# How to remove ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer completely

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a problem related to "ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer". 
I have an ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer map service, which I have added to Map object. This service work as BaseMap. Now I want to add another ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer map service layer to the same Map object. Before adding the new layer, I just removed the previous tiled map service layer by using method `objMap.removeAllLayers()`. But this method only removes the layer not the extent and it create problem when I add a new layer.

So I want to remove completely the ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer (layer, extent, scale etc.).

I have tried all the below methods

1. `objMap.removeAllLayers();`
2. `objMap.removeLayer(objMap.getLayer('myLayerID'));`

Any solution?

Comment: After removing first layer, when I add second layer, the map not get zoom after zoom level 5.

Comment: @StephenLead: My comment seems  to be no longer corrrect. In the 1.x & 2.x version of the API you could change the projection & lods after setting it. It does not seem to be possible in the 3.x version. Hence the answer given by janechii seems to be the best way to do this.

Comment: @StephenLead: you are right. I've deleted my comments.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe thanks for elaborating. I've never worked with pre v3 versions, so it's good to make this distinction!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call destroy on the current map instance then create a new `esri/Map` instance and load the new base map.

See: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#destroy

```
var map1 = new Map('map');
var basemap1 = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(url);
map1.addLayer(basemap1);
...
map1.destroy();
...
var map2 = new Map('map'); // note we load to the same html node
var basemap2 = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(url);
map2.addLayer(basemap2);
```